# how to change the date of creation of a word file

Tags: ms-word

I was wondering if it is possible to change the date of creation of a word file. For instance, I created my word file in 2012, but I want to show it as it is created in 2003. Is this possible? If yes, could you please explain it?

Comment: Why would you want to do this? Note that you'd have to use MS Office 2003 or older (or transform your word file) to make this at all believable...

Comment: I was making a research about a situation. Someone is creating a file in 2007 and shows it like it is created in 2003. There are fonts which are belonged to MS Office 2007, but as I said before, it looks like it is created in MS Office 2003.

Comment: I'm wondering how I can check the real creation date

Comment: if it is already faked - you can't

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To change access time use  time stomp -

http://www.offensive-security.com/metasploit-unleashed/Timestomp

I doesn't know why you would want to do this ? The above is a anti malware and ethical hacking tool as well as penetration testing tool.